# How to jump immediately to callback in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I have this code:

```
$('#banner .bg_wrap:first').stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 500, function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
```

Now, please help, what I want is to instantly jump to the callback function if the user hover faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#banner .bg_wrap:first').stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 500, callbackFunction);

$('#banner .bg_wrap:first').bind("mouseover", callbackFunction);

function callbackFunction(){
            if (this) $(this).remove();
}
```